# C++: Move a particular number to the back, using vector

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, vector

I have the following given vector:

```
  vector<int> arr = {2,1,2,2,2,3,4,2};
```

The goal is to move a target number all the way to the back.  Say target is 2, then final result should be something like:

`arr = {1,3,4,2,2,2,2,2}`

**Attempt**
My approach is to loop through the vector, then if I find a `2`, I would use `push_back` to add to the end, and at the same time, erase the current `2`.

In code, it looks like this:

```
vector<int> moveEndV1(vector<int> &arr, int toMove){
  for (unsigned int i  = 0; i < arr.size() ; i++) {
    if (arr[i] == toMove) {
      arr.push_back(arr[i]);    // add to the end 
      arr.erase(arr.begin()+i); // erase current 
    }
  }
  return arr;
}
```

**Problem** Once we erase the an element, the loop counter is wrong because now it is dealing with a modified vector.
In other words, say we start with the original vector:

```
{2,1,2,2,2,3,4,2}
```

At `i = 0`, the value is `2` so we moved `2` to the back and erased the first `2`.
So we have at `i = 0`:

```
{1,2,2,2,3,4,2,2}
```

This is fine, but then when we go to `i = 1`, the value at `i = 1` is no longer `1` like the original array, but instead it is `2`. This is because we erased an element when we were at `i = 0`. So, at `i = 1`, after push_back and erasing, we get:

```
 {1,2,2,3,4,2,2,2}
```

So far so good, but now if we go to `i = 2`, we get:

```
 {1,2,3,4,2,2,2,2}
```

`i` will keep increasing till the end, and in the end we have that extra `2` at the front.

{1,**2**,3,4,2,2,2,2}

Is there a way to resolve this? Other than writing a separate function to search for this `2` at the front and then move to back?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this easily by using [`std::stable_partition`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_partition):

```
std::stable_partition(arr.begin(), arr.end(), 
                      [toMove](int i) { return i != toMove; });
```

Comment: `std::stable_partition`, probably. The OP seems to want to preserve the order of elements other than `2`

Answer (score 0):

`@cigien` solution is elegant;
but modified your code a bit, will work too;

```
void moveEndV1(std::vector<int> &arr, int toMove){
  
  auto it = arr.begin();

  for ( int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++ )
  {
      if (*it == toMove )
      {
          int val = *it;
          it = arr.erase( it );
          arr.push_back( val );
      }
      else
      {
          ++it;
      }
  }
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A stable partition works, but seems like an overkill (`O(n log n)` time, `O(log n)` space). Since you know your target number, you don't have to push it back immediately. Instead, use two iterators, `src` and `dst`, along the lines of

```
auto dst = arr.begin();
for (auto src = arr.begin(); src != arr.end(); src++) {
    if (*src != toMove) {
        *dst++ = *src;
    }
}

// At this point all non-target numbers are at the beginning of the
// array, and the order is preserved. Fill the rest with the target.

while (dst != arr.end()) {
    *dst++ = toMove;
}
```